# SQL - Output Multiple Rows per Row By Query Depending on Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datediff

Let's say today is **06/30/2013**.

I have table A:

```
| person    mood        date        |
|-----------------------------------|
| guy01     happy       06/07/2013  |
| guy02     sad         12/12/2012  |
| guy02     happy       04/28/2013  |
```

I want an SQL query to somehow check how many months between each date and output that row however many months before the *next change in mood* or *today's month.* If more than one `mood` of the same person changes in the same month, use the latest `mood` in that month.

(For example: if today is `march/2012`, and there is a record saying `bob` was `happy` in `january/2012`, and no more records of `bob` exists, I want to get an output of 3 rows like so: `[bob,happy,01/2012,],[bob,happy,02/2012,],[bob,happy,03/2012,]`)

I want table B:

```
| person    status      month_yr |
|--------------------------------|
| guy01     happy       06/2013  |
| guy02     sad         12/2012  |
| guy02     sad         01/2013  |
| guy02     sad         02/2013  |
| guy02     sad         03/2013  |
| guy02     happy       04/2013  |
| guy02     happy       05/2013  |
| guy02     happy       06/2013  |
```

How shall I do this?

---

*Restrictions:*

- Working with MS SQL Server
- Cannot create tables, procedures, functions, triggers, etc.
- Should work with multiple `mood` changes

Comment: What would you say you have tried so far :)

Comment: I honestly have no idea where to start. More of a OOP guy...

Comment: I would search for the SQL function (DATE-DIFF)

Comment: what year of sql server are you using?

Comment: Using MS SQL Server 2014

Comment: In 2012 they introduced LAG and LEAD. This might help: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: @logixologist Cool beans. But then there's the question of how to create new rows depending on the difference of months obtained by LAG,LEAD.

Comment: @Ibrahim Is it only ever between two or less mood changes?  Or could there be multiple?

Comment: In a single query that would be hard. Why not use a stored procedure. Maybe a temp table that gets updated

Comment: @logixologist ***Edited***